# Update geographical info from another table MySQL

Tags: mysql, geolocation, geocoding, openstreetmap

Good day to all,

I have a performance issue building the following update :

Table POI (Points Of Interest) contains 10 million records with fields for both longitude and latitude (extract from Planet OSM)

Table City contains 145,000 records of most cities in the world also with fields for both longitude and latitude

I would like to associate the foreign key City_ID (no data yet in this field) in table POI to the main ID in the city table. When this is done, I will be able to associate all my POI's to a city. I've tried reverse geocoding, but it proved to be a bad experience and I don't see how I could reverse geocode 10 million records, thus my bet to take the closest city to each POI. But it seems that my SQL query is taking forever on my brand new Macbook Pro 2015 with 16 gigs or RAM. There is something I'm not doing right here ... All lat and long fields are indexed in the MySQL database

I've tried the following query to do so :

```
update poi
set (poi.city_ID, poi.distance) = 

(    select city.ID,
      MIN(111.045* DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(poi.latitude))
                 * COS(RADIANS(city.latitude))
                 * COS(RADIANS(poi.longitude) - RADIANS(city.longitude))
                 + SIN(RADIANS(poi.latitude))
                 * SIN(RADIANS(city.latitude))))) AS distance_in_km
     FROM city 
)
```

Halp !

Cheers

Norm.

Answer (score 0):

Indexing on two separate lat and lon columns stored as floating point numbers does not help. You need to utilize the spatial features of the database, store the lat/lon location in a single column of geography type, and create spatial indexes on that column. See this [article](http://www.percona.com/blog/2013/10/21/using-the-new-spatial-functions-in-mysql-5-6-for-geo-enabled-applications/) for details on spatial features of MySQL.

Comment: it seems that in order to use spatial features, I need to convert my table from Innodb to MyIsam by this command : ALTER TABLE poi ENGINE=MYISAM; but the damn table stays with Innodb ? What the ??? OR I could upgrade from MySQL 5.6 to 5.7 to have spatial features with InnoDB. Not sure if 5.7 is stable yet ...

Comment: Ok ... I'm on to something here !!! :) I did the following to my table : create index idxfaster on poi (latitude, longitude); AND create index idxfasterlong on poi (longitude); I also put some 'WHERE's in my query (bounding box). The query went from 3 seconds to ... (drum roll)  0.3 second !!! yeah !

Comment: Stupid me ... The update statement didn't take o.3 sec !!! I simply queried the table with a simple select and a pair of hard coded longitude and latitude to see how long one single query takes :) I will now try THE update. Stay tuned